# I am not able to import database file (.sql) to a new database using Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

(I use MySQL Workbench 6.0)
There are two existing databases 'A' and 'B' which have 21 and 41 non-empty tables respectively. There are 10 tables which are common to both (table names, primary key, column names, etc). I have created a new schema 'C' which fixes the redundancy.

So a new database with 52 empty tables is ready.

I want to move the existing data from 'A' and 'B', to 'C'.

I tried 'Data Export to Self-COntained File' to A.sql and B.sql and then 'Import Self-Contained File' to Database C.

The import completes successfully with no errors but the tables in database 'C' are all empty.

Please help.. :/

Comment: According to me, Data import just imports the data and will not create the tables for you. You should create the tables in new database and then import the data.

Comment: I have created the tables already, they're empty.

Comment: I have checked the sql dump file, and it will contain the db name also. So open your dump files and when you see some use statement, change it to use "yourdb name". i.e. use C and then save them and try to import them

Comment: Does the dump folder contain the things you're saying even after i exported using 'Self-contained  File' and not the default dump option?

Comment: I am not talking about dump folder, my meaning is to check your .sql files that are created, when you export data.

Comment: Oh, i get it. but the problem in the first place is, the primary & foreign keys are not assigned in the databases A and B. So if i do what you're saying.. the existing primary and foreign keys in the new database will be dropped.